# How do I register users and link some user specific data automatically in registration page with flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

How do I register users and link some user specific data like "username" automatically in registration Screen?

I am currently using email and password for authentication, but I also want to store data given by `NewUsers` from registration automatically to Firebase on entry to my application.

I see Firebase has `displayName`, `UID`, and `PhoneNumber`. Are these the only ones? And it doesn't state how to initiate it from registration screen UI flutter.

```
class RegistrationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'registration_screen';

  @override
  _RegistrationScreenState createState() => _RegistrationScreenState();
}

class _RegistrationScreenState extends State<RegistrationScreen> {
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  bool showSpinner = false;
  String email;
  String password;

  String displayName;

  String userTelephoneNumer;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: ModalProgressHUD(
        inAsyncCall: showSpinner,
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(
                child: Hero(
                  tag: 'logo',
                  child: Container(
                    height: 200.0,
                    child: Image.asset('images/logo.png'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 18.0,
              ),
              TextField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  displayName = value;
                },
                decoration:
                    kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'Enter your UserName'),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 8.0,
              ),
              // TextField(
              //   keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              //   textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              //   onChanged: (value) {

              //     userTelephoneNumer = value;
              //   },
              //   decoration:
              //       kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'Enter your Telephone Number'),
              // ), SizedBox(
              //   height: 8.0,
              // ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 48.0,
              ),
              TextField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  email = value;
                },
                decoration:
                    kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'Enter your email'),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 8.0,
              ),
              TextField(
                obscureText: true,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  password = value;
                },
                decoration: kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(
                    hintText: 'Enter your password'),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 24.0,
              ),
              RoundedButton(
                title: 'Register',
                colour: Colors.blueAccent,
                onPressed: () async {
                  setState(() {
                    showSpinner = true;
                  });
                  try {

                    final newUser = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                        email: email, password: password, );
                    if (newUser != null) {

                    print(displayName);

                    print(userTelephoneNumer);
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, MapScreen.id);
                    }

                    setState(() {
                      showSpinner = false;
                    });
                  } catch (e) {
                    print(e);
                  }
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Authentication does not have the capability of storing general purpose, free-form data on a per-user basis.  You're supposed to use a database for that.  Firbase Auth will give you a UID for the user that you can use as the index into your database to store that per-user data.

You are not limited in what database you can choose.  Firebase has two options (Realtime Database and Firestore), but you can use whatever you choose.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. So does that mean i set up the database first on Firebase and then manipulate it in flutter? Not sure how to go about connecting the user UID with database for new users without doing each database free form separately and then getting it as a stream.

Comment: Yeah, you're going to have to do that.

Comment: Is there documentation for a walk thru?  Not sure where to start and what key words to use in reference to a new database connection.

Comment: There is lots of documentation and samples for Firebase databases for a variety of client platforms.  I suggest starting with a web search.